# Como dinamizar a cor de um texto em uma célula de uma tabela em HTML, utilizando Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
    $(function() { 
        var texto =  $("#question_list tr:nth-child(1) td:nth-child(4)").text();            
        var result = (texto);
                            
        if (result=="Respondido"){
            $("#answers").css("background","#FF0000");
        }else if(result=="Arquivado"){
            $("#answers").css("background","#00FF00");
        }else if(result=="Em Análise"){
            $("#answers").css("color","#0000FF");
        }else if(result=="Aguardando Resposta"){
            $("#answers").css("color","#0000FF");
        }else{
            $("#answers").css("color","#000000");
                }   
        })
```

```html
 <table id="question_list">     
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Título</th>
            <th>Status</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>

        <tbody>

              <tr>
                <td>Teste Arquivo</td>
                <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Teste com upload de arquivo</td>
                <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Teste com upload de arquivo</td>
                <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Teste com Visualização de Arquivos</td>
                <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
              </tr>

              <tr>
                <td>Teste para visualizar arquivo em anexo</td>
                <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
              </tr>
       
      </tbody>

      </table>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

[image: imagem da tabela]

Os textos nas  sofrerão alterações conforme está no código JS podendo ser uma destes valores. O código porém faz com que apenas a primeira linha da tabela apresente a coloração do texto. Como eu fazer para que o mesmo aconteça com as demais linhas da tabela?

Comment: Suas linhas só têm 2 TDs cada, por isso `td:nth-child(4)` não encontra nada.

Comment: Olá, na verdade teria que ser td:nth-child(2), porém o resultado é o mesmo, altera-se o texto da td na primeira linha e das demais não, conforme aparece na imagem. Suspeito que isso deveria ser inserido em um laço for, porém não sei como fazê-lo a partir do código acima.

Answer (score -1):

Não entendi muito bem mas penso que você queria que o texto ficasse todo a azul, era isso? Corra o exemplo em baixo se era isso que você queria.

EDIT:

Corrigido conforme a sua resposta. Faz um loop pelos elementos dentro da tabela e muda a cor consoante o texto.

```js
$("#question_list tr td:nth-child(2)").each(function(index, value)
 {

  var texto = $(this).text();

  if (texto == "Respondido") {
    $(this).css("background", "#FF0000");
  } else if (texto == "Arquivado") {
    $(this).css("background", "#00FF00");
  } else if (texto == "Em Análise") {
    $(this).css("color", "#0000FF");
  } else if (texto == "Aguardando Resposta") {
    $(this).css("color", "#0000FF");
  } else {
    $(this).css("color", "#000000");
  }


 });
```

```html
<table id="question_list">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Título</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>

  <tbody>

    <tr>
      <td>Teste Arquivo</td>
      <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Teste com upload de arquivo</td>
      <td id="answers">Respondido</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Teste com upload de arquivo</td>
      <td id="answers">Arquivado</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Teste com Visualização de Arquivos</td>
      <td id="answers">Em Análise</td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>Teste para visualizar arquivo em anexo</td>
      <td id="answers">Aguardando Resposta</td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>

</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Eu gostaria que o texto da coluna (td) mudasse de cor a cada alteração. Ex.: Se Aguardando Resposta = Azul, Se respondido = Verde... O código acima está funcionando, porém, se na tabela tem 5 linhas, apenas a primeira sofre alterações de acordo com o código e as demais não. Como está na imagem, o "Aguardando Resposta" está azul só na primeira linha.